# Making output in VC++ point to lines of source code

Tags: custom-errors, prebuild

At work we have a prebuild step that reads over our source code and automatically generates data based on some annotations in the code. If the prebuild tags are poorly formatted or it finds something it doesn't know how to deal with it prints an error. Just like other builder errors, these can be clicked on to direct you to the line containing the error.

If I wanted to do something similar, what would I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you just have to format your output so that it matches the output format of the other tools. I'm not sitting here at my compiler but it's something like:

```
filename.cpp:line number: error message
```

Once you match up the format correctly, then the clicking will take care of itself.